# Unable to insert an image with MikTeX

Tags: graphics, errors, miktex

I've been playing around with `LaTeX` using the `MikTeX` console and I am trying to insert an image, but I cannot. I type

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{…}
[…]
\begin{document}
```

However, when typing `\includegraphics{Picture name}` in the main body an error occurs and I cannot go ahead. Is there something that I skip?

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Utility Console is not intended to insert picture. By it you can maintain/nage your MiKTeX installation.

Comment: @Zarko This means that I cannot insert images using MikTex?

Comment: LaTeX is a programming language. You need to create a new file using the editor of your choice, type some LaTeX code in it, which may include picture inserting commands. The MikTeX console isn't a LaTeX editor.

Comment: @Miyase I apologize for not understanding but I am completely new to LaTex .  What are those LaTex editors that I can use? So MikTex is not an appropriate app for producing LaTex documents?

Comment: LaTeX is just like any programming language: you have to install two things. First, the language itself. Second, a programming environment (editor). MikTeX takes care of the first part. For the second part, you can use a specialized editor like TeXstudio, or a general-purpose editor like Visual Studio Code. If you're new, TeXstudio would probably be easier.

Comment: I suggest you to read introductory text about LaTeX:  https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comments.

Answer (score 1):

Right. So, let's say you made your `.tex` file on your desktop. Now you add it into a folder. What you want to do next is add-in that SAME folder, another folder that contains your pictures. They can have whatever name you want. Let's say you add a picture called `picture 1`, and this picture will be in the folder called `pic folder`.
What you want to do now in your `tex` code is this:

- First add `\usepackage{graphicx}` which i see you already did, but for anybody that did not do it already and reads this.
- Secondly, add `\graphicspath{ {./pic folder/} }` right before the beginning of the document.
- Now, let's say you want to add in the middle of the page your `picture 1` content. so what you do, after you write your text, is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{ {./pic folder/} }   %% make sure you get the name right %%

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{picture 1}  %% same here, the name has to be right %%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you dont want to center it just ignore the first and last line of code. Things to add are:

- You can scale it however you like, just change from `scale=2` to anything that fits your.
- Make sure you get the names correctly

Comment: While everything you wrote is correct, the first problem was that the original poster was trying to type code in the MikTeX console. If you want to answer the question that was asked, you should probably address that too.

Comment: Welcome. // You should provide complete code, starting with \documentclass, especially when the question was posted by a beginner of Latex. Please add. Please use Code-tagging instead of the gray bar you created somehow.